# Styling tables using CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors, html-table

I have a problem with styling tables using CSS.

So I have a table in my HTML file:

```
<table class="altrowstable" id="alternatecolor">
<tr>
    <th>Info Header 1</th><th>Info Header 2</th><th>Info Header 3</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Text 1A</td><td>Text 1B</td><td>Text 1C</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Text 2A</td><td>Text 2B</td><td>Text 2C</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Text 3A</td><td>Text 3B</td><td>Text 3C</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Text 4A</td><td>Text 4B</td><td>Text 4C</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Text 5A</td><td>Text 5B</td><td>Text 5C</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Here is my JavaScript file:

```
function altRows(id){
if(document.getElementsByTagName){  

    var table = document.getElementById(id);  
    var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr"); 

    for(i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){          
        if(i % 2 == 0){
            rows[i].className = "evenrowcolor";
        }else{
            rows[i].className = "oddrowcolor";
        }      
    }
  }
 }
 window.onload=function(){
altRows('alternatecolor');
 }
```

And here is my CSS file:

```
table.altrowstable {
    font-family: verdana,arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:11px;
    color:#333333;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #a9c6c9;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
table.altrowstable th {
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 8px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #a9c6c9;
}
table.altrowstable td {
    border-width: 1px;
    padding: 8px;
        border-style: solid;
    border-color: #a9c6c9;
}

table.oddrowcolor{
    background-color:#d4e3e5;
}
table.evenrowcolor{
    background-color:#c3dde0;
}
```

The problem is that it is not changing color neither odd rows nor even odd.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll provide you a CSS solution for this:

```
table.class_name tr:nth-child(odd) {
   /* Styles */
}

table.class_name tr:nth-child(even) {
   /* Styles */
}
```

That's all you need, although it’s not supported in IE 8 and earlier.

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/SWpjd/)

For your table headers, you can simply use a different selector to over ride the background styles like

```
table.altrowstable tr th {
    background: #fff;
}
```

[**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/SWpjd/1/)

Comment: @PaulD.Waite We have [workarounds](http://css3pie.com/documentation/product-comparison/) for that :)

Comment: PIE isn’t a workaround for IE 8 not supporting `:nth-child`. As the page you linked says, “PIE doesn't attempt to implement any CSS3 selectors.”

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Did you read [this](http://css3pie.com/documentation/product-comparison/#selectivizr)?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I expected you to go through, properly... :)

Comment: read more than the first ten words? On the *internet*? *Are you kidding!?*

Answer (score 2):

I did check your code and found a little correction iin the css is needed to get the expected solution. There should be an empty space between the table and row classname.

```
table .oddrowcolor{
   background-color:#d4e3e5;
}
table .evenrowcolor{
   background-color:#c3dde0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I like to provide solutions that dont *tinker* or *modify* the original source much.
Your **HTML** is fine, **JScript** is fine(very fine). Good to see that you use the .classname so that is is cross brwoser compatible.So all i did is change the classes for the **CSS**

*YOUR CODE*

```
table.oddrowcolor {
    background-color:#d4e3e5;
}
table.evenrowcolor {
    background-color:#c3dde0;
}
```

*MY CHANGE*

```
tr.oddrowcolor {
    background-color:#d4e3e5;
}
tr.evenrowcolor {
    background-color:#c3dde0;
}
```

[*WORKING FIDDLE*](http://jsfiddle.net/tHzWc/1/)

total change from your code to mine. 8 characters. Simple ain't it?

Answer (score 0):

You have a problem within your CSS. You are setting the class for table, while as it should be for td.

You also need to modify your below js as style can be applied to `td` and not to `tr`

```
var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("td");
```

Here is the problem in your CSS

```
table.oddrowcolor{
    background-color:#d4e3e5;
}
table.evenrowcolor{
    background-color:#c3dde0;
}
```

You should be using this instead

```
table td.oddrowcolor{
    background-color:#d4e3e5;
}
table td.evenrowcolor{
    background-color:#c3dde0;
}
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4TZfh/7/)

Comment: Have you checked your fiddle. Looks like a checkerboard

Comment: <td> represents a cell ina row. The OP wants the bg color effect to be applied to the <tr>=row rather than a cell.

Comment: @AnaMaria: I updated the fiddle, but my answer is still valid. why downvote?

Answer (score -2):

Try this one ...[**see the Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tHzWc/)

```
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #CCC}
tr:nth-child(odd) {background: #FFF}
```